# A SELECT statement quering all 500+ tables in a DB to return all field with a value james or xyz

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I was wondering if it were possible to write a query that would return all field with value dcf023 from all tables from the DB. The field dcf023  n column title column xyz. This code who select all the column with Column xyz but i need narrow it the field value = dcf023 not the column.

--this code return only the column not the field = --

SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME

FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%Scolumnxyz%'

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Talk about tag spam....which one is it?

Comment: @Rick: I think he forgot to tag it as "spam" ;)

Comment: what do you mean I realy need that no joke

Comment: if you think its very simple to do please give me the answer then.

Comment: @MrSQLDBA dynamic sql. See the documentation for [`exec`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx).

Comment: its not working  saying   :Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: As @canon suggested, you'll need to employ Dynamic SQL through a stored procedure in whatever RDBMS you are using. (You've tagged multiple RDBMS so this is about as helpful as we can be).

Comment: well am using MSSQL server and its not liking it. Need a better simple code.

Answer (score 0):

I sure hope this if for analysis and not something you want to do all the time. Here is a script I have for this type of thing. You will probably want to modify this slightly to filter down the column names but this should get you started. This will generate a series of select statements that you will need to copy and then run.

```
DECLARE @MySearchCriteria VARCHAR(500)
SET @MySearchCriteria = '''10345''' --you do need all these quotation marks because this string is injected to another string.

SELECT 'if exists(SELECT ' + c.columnlist + '] FROM [' + t.name + '] WHERE ' + w.whereclause + ') SELECT ' + c.columnlist + '] FROM [' + t.name + '] WHERE ' + w.whereclause  as SelectStatement
FROM sys.tables t 
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT STUFF((    
        SELECT '], [' + c.Name AS [text()]
        FROM sys.columns c
        join sys.types t2 on t2.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
        WHERE t.object_id = c.object_id 
            AND c.collation_name IS NOT NULL
            AND c.max_length > 6
            and t2.name not in ('text', 'ntext')
        FOR XML PATH('') 
    ), 1, 2, '' )
) c (columnlist)
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT STUFF((    
        SELECT ' OR [' + c.Name + '] IN (' + @MySearchCriteria + ')' AS [text()]
        FROM sys.columns c
        join sys.types t2 on t2.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
        WHERE t.object_id = c.object_id 
            AND c.collation_name IS NOT NULL
            AND c.max_length > 6
            and t2.name not in ('text', 'ntext')
        FOR XML PATH('') 
    ), 1, 4, '' )
) w (whereclause)
where c.columnlist is not null
ORDER BY t.name
```

Comment: This sound like have work at least run I mean. But come up with a lot of select statement  how do you have it to provide only the result, columns and tables not all 2k+ rows of          SELECT  [SystemAssignId], [AccountId], [CompOperId], [PrevAcctId] FROM [AcAccountPointer] WHERE [SystemAssignId] IN ('14348600000000') OR [AccountId] IN ('14348600000000') OR [CompOperId] IN ('14348600000000') OR [PrevAcctId] IN ('14348600000000')

Comment: You have a couple choices. You can either copy and paste the results into a new query window to run them, or you can extend this to execute those results as dynamic sql. This kind of thing should only ever be done as a one off or part of analysis. This should NEVER be done on a regular basis because it is going to be horribly slow.

Comment: its collecting a lot of empty columns. Is there a way to tune it to only bring not empty result?

Comment: Sure just add an exists before the select in the dynamic sql portion. I will edit my answer to show you.

Comment: My concern is that if you couldn't add that bit you don't really understand what this is doing very well. Make sure you understand what this is doing before you use it.